# Why does Charles Lindbergh appear to avoid England in 1927?

Tags: aircraft, 1920s

If you look at [this (admittedly poor) map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright-Bellanca_WB-2#/media/File:Woolaroc_-_Lindbergh_Atlantik%C3%BCberflug.jpg) you see that Charles Lindbergh appears to skirt the English coast on his way to Paris but never go into English "airspace" (not sure such a concept existed at the time?). Were there diplomatic reasons? Or was Lindbergh not welcome in England for some reason?

Answer (score 5):

That map would appear to be misleading. A much more detailed website about the flight, [charleslindbergh.com](http://www.charleslindbergh.com/history/paris.asp), reckons that he flew over England. He said he'd flown a compass course from Cape Valencia and Dingle Bay, where he'd fixed an accurate position, to Paris.

Comment: I mean those maps do look pretty accurate, but why would the newspaper take the time to draw it "wrong"?

Comment: They probably didn't have much information, but had to produce a map, and so drew something that they felt looked good. There is a horrible truth about journalism: much of it is either terribly over-simplified, or just plain wrong. If you're ever involved with an actual news story, you're likely to find the journalists have got it wrong in some important way. This has happened every time I've been involved with one.